# Dollar Sign in Context Free Language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I have a homework about find the pumping lemma in Context Free Language. The last one I couldn't solve:

$L = \{a^i \$ a^{3i} \$ a^{5i}  \mid   i \in \mathbb{N} \}$

What does the dollar symbol mean in this language?

How can I use pumping lemma in this example?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The dollar symbol simply denotes a letter of the alphabet. You could use $b$ instead. But what do you want to prove by using the pumping lemma? And which pumping lemma do yo want to use ?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin The Pumping Lemma for Context-Free Languages. There are a lot of cases i think :(

Comment: But what do you want to prove?

Comment: It is not context free. I want to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

In theory there are several cases, but they all work exactly the same way and can be handled at once.

Start with the word $s=a^p\$a^{3p}\$a^{5p}$, where $p$ is the pumping length. The pumping lemma gives you a decomposition $s=uvwxy$ such that $|vwx|\le p$, $|vx|\ge 1$, and $uv^kwx^ky\in L$ for each $k\ge 0$. Because $|vwx|\le p$, the string $uvw$ can intersect at most two of the blocks of $a$s; use this fact to show easily that pumping $s$ takes you out of $L$.

Comment: I take $ like an letter from alphabet. And I've solved it already. But if it is delimiter, I don't know how to solve :)

Comment: @Zafer: Yes, it’s a letter from the alphabet: the alphabet is $\{,\$\}$ (or some finite superset thereof). In terms of the language $L$, however, $\$$ functions as a delimiter within words, separating the blocks of $a$s.

Answer (score 0):

The dollar symbol here acts as a *delimiter* symbol, it separates the three substrings of $a$s.

Comment: How can i use pumping lemma. $ is like comma? am i right? or not